# Content slides left when touch tinnyscrollbar

Tags: tinyscrollbar

I have a problem with tinyscrollbar that I have used in my site www.halfticket.gr.
Clicking on “halftickets” icon (content Box) to the right in this page everything works fine.

But, if you go to this
[Link](http://www.halfticket.gr/TheaterPages/MainPage/BranchTestMainPage.asp?frm=1000&sindex=2507&pp9=123)
and then Clicking on “halftickets” icon and touching on the scrollbar the content slides 
all the way to the middle of the screen (I use **mozilla**).

The funny thing is that I use the same exactly code in both pages!!

Could you please help me out

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Nehal, I did try everything. The same code is running in two distinct pages but in one there is this strange problem!